# AVPlayerView (AVPlayer) gives error: itemasync_CopyProperty signalled err=-12785

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avkit

I just created a very simple app for OS X using AVPlayerView, which uses a AVPlayer object to display and playback media content.

```
self.playerView.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.fileUrl];
[self.view addSubview:self.playerView];
```

Playing the video works, but I get these errors:

```
[12:37:28.613] itemasync_CopyProperty signalled err=-12785 (kFigBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c line 2088
```

and

```
<<< FFR_Movie >>> ParseEditListAtom: numEntries not consistent with atom data length
<<< FFR_Movie >>> ParseSampleSizeAtom: numEntries not consistent with atom data length
<<< FFR_Movie >>> ParseSyncSampleAtom: numEntries not consistent with atom data length
<<< FFR_Movie >>> ParseChunkOffset64Atom: numEntries not consistent with atom data length
<<< FFR_Movie >>> ParseEditListAtom: numEntries not consistent with atom data length
```

I've seen others on the web having similar problems, but didn't find any answer.
The item I'm playing is session 606 from WWDC 2013 (a .mov)